# ZF2 set cookie inside the module

Tags: php, cookies, zend-framework2

I am trying to set a cookie at the second page request inside the module.php. My page request session setter works well but somehow the cookie isn't set. Is there an explanation why this cookie isn't set?

Module.php

```
    public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
    {
        $application          = $e->getApplication();
        $eventManager        = $application->getEventManager();
        $moduleRouteListener = new ModuleRouteListener();
        $moduleRouteListener ->attach($eventManager);
        $serviceManager      = $application->getServiceManager();
        //..
        if (php_sapi_name() !== 'cli') {
            //....
            $this->_setUserTrackingCookie($serviceManager);
        }
    }

    private function _setUserTrackingCookie($serviceManager)
    {
        $request  = $serviceManager->get('Request');
        $headers  = $request->getHeaders();
        $cookies  = $request->getCookie();
        if (!$cookies->offsetExists('fzz')) {
            $acceptingCookies = new Container('fzz');
            if (!$acceptingCookies->offsetExists('requests')) {
                $acceptingCookies->offsetSet('requests', 1);
            } else {
                $cookieSalt          = Rand::getString(32, 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890', true);
                $dbAdapter           = $serviceManager->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                $table               = new \Application\Model\UserCookieTable($dbAdapter);
                $userCookie          = new UserCookie();
                $userCookie->salt    = $cookieSalt;
                $userCookie->country = $country;
                $table               ->insertUserCookie($userCookie);
                $locationCookie      = new SetCookie('fzz', 'testing_cookie', strtotime('+1 Year', time()), '/');
                $headers             ->addHeader($locationCookie);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Triming down your code a little bit, the cookie setting part reads as:

```
$request  = $serviceManager->get('Request');
$headers  = $request->getHeaders();
$locationCookie = new SetCookie('fzz', 'testing_cookie', strtotime('+1 Year', time()), '/');
$headers->addHeader($locationCookie);
```

You're adding a a cookie to the `Representation of the Request`. While this works quite fine for the representation, we cannot actually modify the request of course.

What you actually want to do is to add the Cookie header to the `Response` instead:

```
$response = $serviceManager->get('Response');
$headers  = $response ->getHeaders();
$locationCookie = new SetCookie('fzz', 'testing_cookie', strtotime('+1 Year', time()), '/');
$headers->addHeader($locationCookie);
```

There is by the way a more `Zf-way` of checking for an actual HTTP request:

```
if ($request instanceof \Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request) {
    $headers  = $response ->getHeaders();
    $locationCookie = new SetCookie('fzz', 'testing_cookie', strtotime('+1 Year', time()), '/');
    $headers->addHeader($locationCookie);
}
```

On the CLI, `$request` will be an instance of `Zend\Console\Request` instead.